# Continuous compounding and annual contributions

Tags: finance

I have to find a formula for a problem that involves yearly continuous compounding at 2% with annual contributions of 5000$.
We know y(0)=0, so there is initially no money in this account.

Let FV= Future value, n= number of years that have passed,P= initial value of account, i= interest rate in decimals.

Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I know that continuous compounding is calculated with FV=P*e^(ni) , I just don't understand how to take into account the annual contributions

Comment: You just have a geometric progression.  $e^{n\iota}=\left(e^\iota\right)^n$

Comment: How do I turn that into a complete formula that gives me the amount in the account for every year? @saulspatz

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Suppose you want to start saving for retirement. You decide to continuously invest $5000 of your income each year in a risk-free investment with a 2% yearly interest rate, compounded continuously. Find the equation for y(t) (the amount of money in the account at any given year). @saulspatz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a formula for the amount in the account at the end of $n$ years.  There have been $n$ contributions of $5000$ each, which have been in the account earning interest, for $n,n-1,n-2,\dots,1$ years.  Their accumulated value is $$5000\sum_{k=1}^ne^{.02k}=5000\sum_{k=1}^n\left(e^{.02}\right)^k=5000{e^{.02(n+1)}-e^{.02}\over e^{.02}-1}$$

To find the value at time $n+t$, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $0<t<1$, we have only to multiply by $e^{.02t}$.

Comment: It says the answer is wrong. If it helps, we know that after 35 years, there is 253439$ in the account @saulspatz

Comment: What says that the answer is wrong?  What did you get for the answer after $35$ years with my formula?  What mistakes do you see in my derivation of the formula?

Comment: I'm using WebWork and the formula it says the formula is not correct. With your formula I got 255981$

Comment: Try dividing their answer by mine.  What do you conclude?

Comment: @AlexG  Have you figured it out?

Comment: Yes I have. @saulspatz

Answer (score 0):

The expression for the future value  of the account in $n$-year is

$$\text{FV}(n)=5000 [e^{0.02(n-1)}+e^{0.02(n-2)}+e^{0.02(n-3)}+ \>...\> e^{0.02}+1]$$

which is a geometric series and can be summed as,

$$\text{FV}(n)=5000 \frac{ e^{0.02n}-1}{e^{0.02}-1}$$

So, you have

$$FV(1)=5000$$
$$FV(2) = 5000(1+e^{0.02})$$
$$...$$

Comment: It says the answer is wrong. If it helps, we know that after 35 years, there is 253439$ in the account @Quanto

Comment: @Alex.G - you'd get 253439 if you use a similar version $\text{FV}(35)=5000 \frac{ e^{0.02\times 35}-1}{0.02}$. But, then, it is no longer continuous compounding.

Comment: That was the correct equation thank you so much! My professor probably didn't write the correct instruction. @Quanto

Comment: @Alex.G - no problem